# Custom Autocomplete Component Ember Cli not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I not sure why the return is not being passed to the component template.  It's listening and the value is found but its not working.

return result.resources; is not returning the data when result.resoures has an array of objects.

here is the autocomplete template auto-complete.hbs

```
    <ul>
        <li class='row input-group-lg'>
            {{input type="text" value=searchText placeholder="Enter Street Address" class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12 street-address'}}
        </li>


    </ul>
    <ul>
        {{#each searchResults}}
            <li>{{this.name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

here is auto-complete.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
        searchText: null,

        searchResults: function() {
            var searchText = this.get('searchText');
            if(!searchText) {
                return;
            }
            Ember.$.ajax({
                url: "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    key: "",
                    q: searchText
                },
                jsonp: "jsonp"
            }).then(function(data) {
                var result = data.resourceSets[0];
                if (result) {
                    if (result.estimatedTotal > 0) {
                        return result.resources;
                    }
                }
            });
        }.property('searchText')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code block

```
.then(function(data) {
            var result = data.resourceSets[0];
            if (result) {
                if (result.estimatedTotal > 0) {
                    return result.resources;
                }
            }
```

will return from the `promise` and will not return the value for the computed property, which obviously means that you are not returning anything for the CP.

A possible work around can be

```
searchResults: function() {
        var searchText = this.get('searchText');
        var searchResults = Ember.ArrayProxy.create();
        if(!searchText) {
            return;
        }
        Ember.$.ajax({
            url: "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                key: "",
                q: searchText
            },
            jsonp: "jsonp"
        }).then(function(data) {
            var result = data.resourceSets[0];
            if (result) {
                if (result.estimatedTotal > 0) {
                    searchResults.set('content',result.resources);
                }
            }
        });
        return searchResults;
    }.property('searchText')
```

You can create an arrayproxy and return the arrayproxy for the CP. Upon completion of the promise, set the result as content to the arrayproxy, which will update the template.